# Closing the div and again re-open when click on button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a scenario where when I click on "x" button the div shown in the screen shot (REGULAR 50ML) has to close and when I click on Topping button, again this div has to be re-opened. These values are dynamically generated.

This is my code that I tried where `"div#"+id_attr_val+".Topping-details"` is div id, `".btn btn-sm topp "` is button class and `".topping-close"` is close class :

```
function setStuff(activateEvent, activateUi) {    
    var selectedeleemnt = activateUi.newHeader.text();
    var response = search(selectedeleemnt);
    if (selectedeleemnt != null && activateUi.newPanel.html() == '') {
        var activateUiHTML = $("<div class='inner-accordion'></div>");
        activateUiHTML.append('<div id="' + v_item_id + '" class="activateUiHTML"  data-role="collapsible">');
    }
}

function display() {
    toplevelcart += '<section id="topping_tsection_'+id_attr_val+'"><i id="topping-close" class="topping-close"></i>';
    $("div#"+id_attr_val+".Topping-details").each(function(i) {          
        $(this).hide().delay(i * 1500).fadeIn(1500);
    });
    $('.topping-close').one('click', function() {
        $(this).closest("div#"+id_attr_val+".Topping-details").fadeOut();
    });
}
```

I am able to close the div, but could not reopen the div. Please help me out.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hM6ZT/

Comment: @user3189916 your fiddle sample does nothing neither it closes nor opens :(

Answer (score 1):

Try using following:

```
$("#divID").slideToggle(1000);
```

`.slideToggle(milliseconds)`: this will Close the `div` if already opened & vice versa.

Comment: i removed fadeIn and fadeOut functions in my code and added yours, but no luck. I am getting same result, it is just closing and not re-opening.

Comment: It's not working for me. My requirement is "When i click on close(id="topping-close"), the div(id="div#"+id_attr_val+".Topping-details") has to be closed and when i click on the button (id = ".btn btn-sm topp "), the div(id="div#"+id_attr_val+".Topping-details") has to be opened".

Answer (score 0):

```
  use this example as reference

    <div id="main" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid">
        <!-- div that is to show/hide goes inside parent div #main-->
        <div id="A">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
    </div>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function() 
     {
        $("#main").click(function()
        {
            $("#A").slideToggle(1000);
        }); 
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: It's not working for me. My requirement is "When i click on close(id="topping-close"), the div(id="div#"+id_attr_val+".Topping-details") has to be closed and when i click on the button (id = ".btn btn-sm topp "), the div(id="div#"+id_attr_val+".Topping-details") has to be opened".

Comment: this must work..and your fiddle is not complete as such. it does not open no close. and no available classes/dives that u mentioned..in fiddle